# Why do I get a -1 point every time I downvote a post?

Tags: support, down-votes, reputation

Do you lose reputation for downvoting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you lose reputation for downvoting answers (but not questions). See [this post on the central meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15863/263383) for more discussion on this.